# Confused with generics and subtyping

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, raw-types

So, let's say we have a simple interface

```
public interface ICopyable<T> {
    void copyFrom(T original);
}
```

Which basically adds a copyFrom method with a parameterized type. And you have an interface extending it:

```
public interface ISomeObject<T> extends ICopyable<T> {
    String getType();
}
```

The interface isn't adding anything valuable of course apart of it's type, but let's pretend there are some useful methods in it. The idea is still the same - all objects of this interface have a getType() method and they can copy one object of THE SAME TYPE from one to the other.

Now let's have two implementations of this interface, and the second implementation inherits from the first one:

```
public static class ActualObject1 implements ISomeObject<ActualObject1> {
    Object data1;

    @Override public void copyFrom(final ActualObject1 original) {
        this.data1 = original.data1;
    }

    @Override public String getType() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public static class ActualObject2 extends ActualObject1 {
    Object data2;

    @Override public void copyFrom(final ActualObject1 original) {
        super.copyFrom(original);
        // oh no! i've just realized that i'm not copying the ActualObject2!
    }
}
```

So the second's object(ActualObject2) is supposed to extend the ActualObject1, but if it's done this way it can't implement the right "copyFrom" method, as the first class implements the interface ISomeObject for itself only. And it obviously wants to do it somehow to allow copying of ActualObject2's to each other. But how?

It can't just declare implements ISomeObject as it'll clash with it's parent's implementation type.
So you'll want to do something like that maybe?

```
public static class ActualObject1<T extends ActualObject1> implements ISomeObject<T> {
    Object data1;

    @Override public void copyFrom(final ActualObject1 original) {
        this.data1 = original.data1;
    }

    @Override public String getType() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}

public static class ActualObject2 extends ActualObject1<ActualObject2> {
    Object data2;

    @Override public void copyFrom(final ActualObject2 original) {
        super.copyFrom(original);
        this.data2 = original.data2;
    }
}
```

Basically parameterizing the class1, and class2 specifies itself as a parameter. It all works fine, you can create instances of both types:

```
ActualObject1 obj1 = new ActualObject1();
```

However there's one "little" problem - the obj1 has a raw type. The full declaration looks rather silly:

```
ActualObject1<ActualObject1> obj2 = new ActualObject1<>();
```

But it works. However the "raw type" nature of this class can bite for example in this scanario:

```
public static class SomeOtherParameterizedClass<T extends ISomeObject<T>> {
    void copyObjects(T obj1, T obj2) {
        obj1.copyFrom(obj2);
    }
}
```

So you're creating some random class parameterized by <T extends ISomeObject<T>>. And you can in theory say it like that: <T extends ISomeObject> but then you won't be able to use T in the "copyFrom" safely. In other words - it's a valid class parameterization, it has a point.

But then you can't parameterize it for ActualObject1:

```
SomeOtherParameterizedClass<ActualObject1> a1 = new SomeOtherParameterizedClass<>();
```

Yea - doesn't work. Hint:

```
SomeOtherParameterizedClass<ActualObject2> a2 = new SomeOtherParameterizedClass<>();
```

Works just fine...

So what's the right approach here? I'm more interested in retaining the type safety as much as possible, as for sure you can just use raw types all the way and don't worry about anything, but it's for the weak! :-)

We're in statically typed language so it's somewhat of an academic question - what's the right way of designing this class hierarchies with generics? Is occasionally using raw-types actually required for those to work?

Comment: Part of the problem here is due to having concrete base classes, which are often viewed as a code smell.

Comment: Part of the issue may be your definition of "copy", which is just a reference to an object which has a hierarchical relationship with its copy destination.  `ActualObject2` is-an `ActualObject1` by virtue of their inheritance chain, so there's no need whatsoever to use `Object`.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't quite get both replies... what would you do instead?